# How to center Font Awesome icons horizontally?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a table with a [**Font Awesome**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon and I want to align text left and center icons.
I tried with centering `<i>` but doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<td><i class="icon-ok"></i></td>
```

CSS:

```
td, th {
    text-align: left;
}
td i {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kB6Ju/1/)**

I also tried to set `text-align:center !important;` but doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Add your own flavour of the font awesome style

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

which along with your

```
td i {
    text-align:center;
}
```

should center just the icons.

Comment: Using both `^=` and `*=` to check if the `class` attribute contains `icon-` is redundant. Use `[class*="icon-"]` (without the space), what will have the same effect.

Answer (score 31):

Use [`text-align: center;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align0) on the block container of the icon (the `<td>`) - text-align doesn't apply to inline elements, only block containers:

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kB6Ju/2/

Comment: Thank you! but as I said I want to align text to left and center icons.

Comment: It would be easiest to give the relevant icon `<td>`s a class

Comment: You can use `td:nth-child(n + 4) {text-align: center;}` so that only the fourth and fifth `<td>` are centered in each row (assuming the HTML doesn't change) - http://jsfiddle.net/kB6Ju/3/

Comment: I can't assign a class to `<td>` because the table is dynamic. I can try to assign `class="icon"` to all `td`'s that have a child `<i>` using jQuery. But I don't know if it's a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

Give a class to your cell containing the icon

```
<td class="icon"><i class="icon-ok"></i></td>
```

and then

```
.icon{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But my table is dynamic and i can't assign a class to `<td>`.

Answer (score 8):

i solved my problem with this:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"></div>
```

im using bootstrap with font awesome icons.

if you want to know more acess the link below:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 5):

OP you can use attribute selectors to get the result you desire. Here is the extra code you add

```
tr td i[class*="icon"] {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kB6Ju/5/

Answer (score 5):

*It's a really old topic but as it still comes up top in search results:*

Nowadays you can add additional class `fa-fw` to set it fixed width.

Example:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't want to add a class to cells containing an icon, how about this...

Wrap the contents of each non-icon `td` in a `span`:

```
<td><span>consectetur</span></td>
<td><span>adipiscing</span></td>
<td><span>elit</span></td>
```

And use this CSS:

```css
td {
    text-align: center;
}
td span {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

I wouldn't normally post an answer in this situation, but this seems too long for a comment.

Answer (score 4):

If your icons are in an icon stack you can use the following code:

```
.icon-stack{ margin: auto; display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `margin` to solve this issue. In my case setting margin to 3 pixels solved the problem. This is the example:

```
<i class="fas fa-file-upload" style="margin: 3px;">
```

Obviously, 3 pixels are not necessarily enough in your case, so I suggest you do some tests.

NOTE: I'm using this inside a flex element so I'm not sure if in a table it's same.