# Shifting text and icon in popup from right to left and vice versa

Tags: css, angular, popup

I have a popup, where it shows icon in the right side and text in the left side

[Click here to see demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-font-awesome-example-mpduzt)

**App Module.ts**

```
SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot( {
      icons: {
        success: '<i class="icon-check-sign icon-3x"></i>',
        alert: '<i class="icon-exclamation icon-3x"></i>',
        error: '<i class="icon-bug icon-3x"></i>',
        info: '<i class="icon-info icon-3x"></i>',
        warn: '<i class="icon-warning-sign icon-3x"></i>'
      }
    })
```

**CSS**

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

td i {
    text-align:left;
}
```

> Now I want to flip it, like icon on the left and text on the right.

This is the source code: https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications

But I would like to do without altering the source code, by only changing the CSS classes

*I find the question here in stack overflow*

[How to center Font Awesome icons horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162889/how-to-center-font-awesome-icons-horizontally)

and solution and implemented extra classes which shown in the accepted solution. But there is no difference.

**How can I flip the icon and text?**

Comment: Please share your code here in a stackOverflow snippet. Not on external links. Create a minimal example with your code that replicates the problem.

Comment: changed as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these styles

```
<style>
   .simple-notification .icon {
      left: 0 !important;
  }


  .simple-notification.has-icon .sn-title, .simple-notification.has-icon .sn-content, .simple-notification.has-icon .sn-html {
      padding: 0 0px 0px 50px !important;
  }
  </style>
```

See updated [snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-font-awesome-example-vi7em3?file=index.html)

Comment: I have added these styles directly in index.html, but you should ideally create a separate Css file for it and add these styles in them

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the quick turnaround!